# How to block subdomain direct access

Tags: networking, hosting, load-balancing, web-hosting, subdomain

How to block subdomain direct access. I want to allow the subdomain only through the main domain.

EX: facebook does not allows chat.facebook.com directly. Like this way how to block sub domains direct access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a tricky way to implement that. For example, when you access your sub domain from your main domain, you can create a session or cookie from your main domain and store it in the sub domain database. Then every access to the sub domain, it will compare current session with one stored in the database.

By this way, every direct access to sub domain other than from main domain can be denied caused no session is store in database to be compared.